# What is the point of encrypting web.config if user can just decrypt it?

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config

Oi, some vendor is telling my bosses that not encrypting the web.config is big security hole. This sounds like bunk to me. I mean, if someone compromises the server aren't we screwed anyways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The encryption does not mean that you are protected. The private key needed for decryption is stored on the server, so if your server is compromised your web.config can be decrypted.

We only encrypt the connection string section of the web.config. It helps prevent other prying eyes from easily accessing our connection strings especially in the development environment (*which is often much less secure than your production environments*).

The encryption is just a small piece to the layered security.  It is by no means an end-all solution for protecting your sensitive information.

Answer (score 6):

Like @Joelt suggested, ASP.NET had a security issue semi recently that allowed people to access files in the root web etc. Now, this issue could have existed for a long time. Alternatively, there could be a secret flaw right now that no one knows about except some leet punks ... which means we're all vulnerable right now. I mean, until the ASP.NET team (and security people a week or two before them) announced that previous flaw ... how long was that out in the wild? How many people exploited that?

So - that's the general idea. If for some reason a flaw exists - where people can remotely gain access to files - including web.config - then your data could be known.

Now - the kicker is this. So .. someone might find out about my DB name, DB ip addy and DB password .. right? but they need to access my internal DB ... so good luck there. BUT, my web.config might have my twitter username password in there? (*Ding! light just turned on*). My 3rd party api username/passwords. etc.

THAT is where the real security issue lies, IMO.

I'd hate it if u learn my companies twitter username/password and then start defacing our twitter account.

Comment: +1 for mentioning other types of sensitive data than just the connection string.

Answer (score 2):

There was a recently released security hole in ASP.net that would have allowed a remote user to access any file in the web root, including web.config, without accessing the entire server. Additionally, there may be login information in the web.config that allows compromising one server to compromise another.

Comment: Ok, so someone remotely views the web config, gets the DB credentials. Then they would need some sort of hole to get onto our network right?

Comment: If I know your connection string, I can use SQL Server remotely to do anything I want with your database.

Comment: if you're using basic membership/role/user provider in asp.net it allows you to store usernames and passwords in cleartext in your web.config. We can always argue whether ppl doing that should be sent direcly on the mental institution, but it doesn't change the fact that you CAN and ppl DO have sensetive data in their web.config.

Comment: @jonathan include anyone who exposes their SQL server remotely (on the internet) to the list of people who needs to be sent to the mental institution :P

Comment: @Pauli: I'm not sure I follow. It is normal for SQL Servers to be connected to the web. Having the server on a separate machine from the website provides better performance. And if it's not on the web, how can users work with the data?

Comment: @jonathan yes, thats why add internet i parenthesis. Of course you need remote access to it, like from the webserver. But internet-wise clients should ONLY have access webserver (ideally only on port 80 and 443), not the sql server.

Comment: @Pauli: I'm certainly not an expert on server administration. Are you saying those ports work over the Web or not? If I don't own the server and it's not at my location, how should I be accessing it?

Comment: @Jonathan, you're the who claimed that knowing the connection string was all it takes to 0wn a database. The whole point of firewalls and a DMZ is to ensure that isn't possible - you'd have to own the webserver or find an SQL injection to get any kind of direct connectivity.

Comment: Guys -> re: SQL Server (or any DB) that can be remotely connected. You _DO NOT_ (and should not) give it a Public IP address, which means it can be accessed via the web. Always give it a private IP address. Then use either VPN (recommended) or Remote Desktop via another public facing server (eg. a web server which HAS to have a public ip). If the web servers and the db server can see each other via their private IP's, then you're good to go. <-- Web Administration 101.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. In my case, I host on a shared hosting account. So a lot of people have access to my account and the files stored there.

Personally, I don't worry about it too much. But, if someone had a mind to, they could access that information. And even if you own the server, if it's a company then there could be a lot of people who have access to it.

For critical data, encrypting it makes sense.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, if someone sees your encrypted config file couldn't they also just see the files that contain the code and figure out how you encrypted it?

Comment: A casual glance at an unencrypted password is all that's needed. If encrypted, they'd need to see the encrypted data, any password/keys used, need to know the algorithm used, and would need to run the algorithm on a computer. And all of the data would be far harder to remember. I'm not saying no one could ever decrypt the data, only that it would be more likely if it could be done casually.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: Why are you saying `And even if you own the server, if it's a company then there could be a lot of people who have access to it.` What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Lorenzo: I'm not sure where the point of confusion is but I'm saying if you have a company with employees, and you host your site on a company computer, there could potentially be times when web.config is seen by an employee that you would not otherwise want to have access to that information. For example, someone not directly involved in the development.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: My confusion was related to "even if you own the server" but now I realized that you was referring to a particular scenario that is not my case. thanks for the explanation